# How can I change what's being typed on key press?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want to type Greek Question Mark (`;` - Unicode 037E) instead of Semicolon (`;` - Unicode 003B) when I press semicolon (keycode 47). Preferably should use a terminal command or a script to change what's being typed. Only need a explanation how would this work, I can construct the script myself.

Comment: Because I want only the semicolon changed, nothing else. And  I want to keep other things from current layout like polish characters.

Comment: There are several Q & A's related to this question that [at first glance](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=askubuntu+remap+keys&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) appear to be version related. I'm pretty certain this has been asked and answered but absent any further information like the output of `lsb_release -a` I'm unable to point you in exactly the right direction.